# When restart one app, stops another app node.js

Tags: node.js

I have two node.js apps running on the same server. When I restart one app listening on port 7777, it stops the other app running on port 8044 even though they are running on two different ports. How can I fix this?

here's the code

aut/app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express'),
    testsConfig = require('./config/testsConfig');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('ROOT');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/aut', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body && req.body.secret && req.body.secret == "danzellovestodance") {
        res.send(testsConfig);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});


module.exports = app;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var webhook = require('./git-webhook/app');
var aut = require('./aut/app');
http.createServer(webhook).listen(7777);
http.createServer(aut).listen(8044);
```

I used to separate each server into a different app.js file, but when I started one server, it stopped the other one

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
  forever start -l /opt/aut.log -a /opt/aut/app.js
  echo "Started"
elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
  forever stopall
  echo "Stopped"
elif [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
  forever stopall
  forever start -l /opt/aut.log -a /opt/aut/app.js
  echo "Restarted"
elif [[ "$1" = "logs" || "$1" = "log" ]]; then
  tail -f /opt/aut.log
else
  echo 'Invalid command. You can only use "start", "stop", "restart", or "logs"'
fi
```

Comment: How are you restarting the app?

Comment: How are the apps set up on the server? How are you restarting them? Without details, we have no idea what the issue may be.

Comment: I added the code above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only have a single Node application that starts two servers.

When you restart the application, it takes down all of the servers that it is running.

You'll actually have to create a second Node application for the second server if you want them to be able to be controlled independently.

Comment: I tried that but if I restart one server it stops the second one

Comment: @Jasmine - You can't just stop one server in the application. You can only stop the application. You need to split your application into two separate applications. Only then will you be able to control one without affecting the other.